About momentum states covariant normalization
I'm following QFT of Schwrtz and I have a doubt about Eq. (2.72).
In particular, from Eq. (2.69): $$[a_k,a_p^\dagger]=(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{k}),\tag{2.69}$$ and Eq. (2.70): $$a_p^\dagger|0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}}|\vec{p}\rangle,\tag{2.70}$$ it follows that:
$$
\langle\vec{p}|\vec{k}\rangle=2\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}\langle0|a_pa_k^\dagger|0\rangle=2\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}\langle0|(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{k})+a_k^\dagger a_p|0\rangle=2\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{k}),
$$
provided by $\langle0|0\rangle=1$.
Nevertheless, Eq.(2.72) states:
$$
\langle\vec{p}|\vec{k}\rangle=2\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}\langle0|a_pa_k^\dagger|0\rangle=2\omega_p(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{k}).\tag{2.72}
$$
My question is: how the squared root $\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}$ is transformed into $\omega_p$?

That Dirac delta distribution makes $\vec p=\vec k$ and so $\sqrt{\omega_p\omega_k}=\omega_p$
